# RadioButton.Checked Error: Control.Checked cannot appear on the left hand side of += or -=

Tags: c#, wpf, if-statement

I am having the strangest problem, and I have to be missing something.

Here is my code that is causing the error.

```
if (radLot.Checked == true)
{
    SymbolSpecification = "LotRenderer";
}

if (radWaterMeter.Checked == true)
{
    SymbolSpecification = "WaterMeterRenderer";
}
```

As you can see, I don't even use =+ or -=... I actually don't have it anywhere in my code... Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What line does the error appear on?

Comment: Instead of testing if true, test w/ the checkedstate.checked.

Comment: I guess the error is: *The event 'Control.Checked' **can only** appear on the left hand side of += or -= (except when used from within the type 'Control')* Reading fail.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`Checked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.checked) is the name of the event that is raised when a `ToggleButton` is checked. (The `RadioButton` class derives from `ToggleButton`.)

I assume you want to access the [`IsChecked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked) property, which gets (or sets) whether the `ToggleButton` is checked.

```
if (radLot.IsChecked == true)
{
    SymbolSpecification = "LotRenderer";
}
```

Hint: Most boolean properties related to the visual state start with `Is—` in WPF.

Comment: I used IsChecked at first and it for some reason always said that the Water Meter radButton was checked.. I have no idea why... but I am going to try the CheckedState Method, I had forgotten all about it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is the radio button getting visually unchecked? If your radio buttons do not belong to the same parent, then you need to group them (using [`GroupName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.radiobutton.groupname.aspx)) to enforce mutual exclusivity (meaning that checking one causes the other to get unchecked).

Answer (score 3):

Alternative you can check the CheckState to perform your statement.

```
 if (radLot.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
            {

            }
```

Edit: 
This will only work when writing a winform application. It will not work with WPF. Use Douglas' answer for WPF.

Comment: +1: Valid alternative. I usually use that property for check boxes supporting three states (including indeterminate).

Comment: @Douglas I started doing it this way when first learning c#; It helps readability when your new. But after I became more seasoned, I started using your method.

Comment: It is not recognizing CheckState.. I don't think CheckState is a method when using radiobuttons..

Comment: You’re right; it was present in WinForms but not in WPF. To get indeterminate states, you now need to check for `IsChecked == null`.

Comment: Ya your right! I was thinking only in winforms. Updating the post.

Comment: Thank you @Douglas for your help. The whole problem ended up being with something completely different (isn't that how it always goes? :p ) I'm using arcGIS and I have only been using it for a couple of days so I have not quite grasped the concept of the layers. This problem actually helped me learn how they work though haha! Thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed true - just hit this problem myself converting from `Winforms` to `WPF`.

In `WPF` using:

```
if (radiobutton1.IsChecked == true)
```

works

BUT

```
if (radiobutton1.IsChecked)
```

Does not.

However in `WinForms`

```
if (radiobutton1.Checked)
```

works but does not in `WPF`.