# radiobutton checked validation throws an error

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, radio-button

I'm having some trouble with  radio button validation in a wpf application, the `radiobutton.checked` function it throws an error. the 2 radio buttons are name `TSBtn` and `DSBtn`. the error that I get when I try and build the application is'

> Error 2   The event 'System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton.Checked' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=   115 23  MainServerWIndow

im not sure why this is happening the code I have Writen is bellow'

```
        private void Bill_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (TSBtn.Checked)
        {
            StringBuilder itm = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (object selectedItem in yourOrder.Items)
            {
                 itm.AppendLine(selectedItem.ToString());
            }
            MessageBox.Show("The server is " + serversname.SelectedItem + "\n" + "The table number is " + int.Parse(TableNumber.Text) + "\n" + itm);
        }
        else if (DSBtn.Checked)
        {
            yourOrder.Items.Add("The driver is " + DriverName.SelectedItem);
            yourOrder.Items.Add("Delivery Address " + DeliveryAddress.Text);
        }
    }
```

does anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening?
thanks.

Comment: what occurs if you add `== true` to the conditional?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RadioButton.Checked Error: Control.Checked cannot appear on the left hand side of += or -=](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004382/radiobutton-checked-error-control-checked-cannot-appear-on-the-left-hand-side-o)

Answer (score 1):

Your answer lies in the error message.

> The event 'System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton.Checked' ...

[Checked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.checked(v=vs.110).aspx) is an event, not a property.

What you want is the [IsChecked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Answer (score 0):

`Checked` is an Event. You should be testing the checked property which is `IsChecked`.

So your code should read:

```
if (TSBtn.IsChecked)
...
```

and

```
else if (DSBtn.IsChecked)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found this question solved at:

[stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004382/radiobutton-checked-error-control-checked-cannot-appear-on-the-left-hand-side-o)

```
if (radLot.IsChecked == true)
{
    SymbolSpecification = "LotRenderer";
}
```

Comment: Could you update this comment and expand on the answer please? It would be a higher quality answer than a link and a couple of lines of code.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here. I could, but I'd only copy the answer that I found at the link. I only wanted to share here the other answer I've found.