# If radio button is checked not working

Tags: c#, radio-button, checked

I have four radio buttons where one is called rb_four, and when this is checked, I want something to happen. When I type the following:

```
if (rb_fourp.Checked)
        {

        }
```

I get an error saying: The event ToggleButton.Checked can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=. What am I doing wrong here?

For info, this is the xaml code for the radio button:

```
<RadioButton Name="rb_fourp" Width="150" Height="150" Checked="rb_fourp_Checked">
```

Comment: because you are using an event Check like a member, try to use value instead (if i remember right)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004382/radiobutton-checked-error-control-checked-cannot-appear-on-the-left-hand-side-o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checked is the name of the event that is raised when clicking the radio button.

The `IsChecked` property would be the value you would want to check

```
if(rb_four.IsChecked){ do some code  }
```

Comment: "if(rb_four.IsChecked == true" did it for me, thank you!